# PHP CURL from a specific server to another specific server not working

Tags: php, curl

I have two servers s1 and s2. I have a file from s1 trying to access a file from s2 through php curl. The curl commands are written using php in s1/test.php and it is requesting s2/file.php.

I tested if curl is present in s1 and it is working fine with all urls except from s2. Also I can access s2 from localhost but not from s1. Please help me.

Here is my curl code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "here the url is placed");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$data)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
            curl_close($ch);
            echo $data;
```

When i execute I am getting: "Curl error: couldn't connect to host"

Comment: Have you tried connecting from the command line already as well with wget or curl or even telnet? Might be a firewall issue of some sorts, not necessarily PHP related.

Comment: DNS ?? Firewall ?? Can you telnet from s1 to s2 ??

Comment: @Blizz the url is working fine from localhost curl

Comment: @ManseUK how to do telnet from s1 to s2? also how can i find if any firewall or dns issue is there with my cpanel hosting?

Comment: @JobyJoseph: Just wondering, is it a HTTPS url of some sorts? If you are using a self signed certificate for example you need to add another option to curl to indicate it needs to accept those too.

Comment: @blizz it is not https. its normal http connection

Comment: @JobyJoseph: Can you try to use curl_errno() to see what error exactly you are getting? (http://php.net/curl_errno)

Comment: @JobyJoseph open a command prompt on s1 and type `telnet s2 80` and hit enter - if you get a connection (the command prompt will go blank) then your route is fine and its a problem with the PHP code

Comment: @manseuk s1 is shared hosting. how can i execute telnet command there?

Answer (score 0):

`couldn't connect to host` means that sonmething is wrong with the connection between the 2 servers. Check DNS's, ip's firewalls, opened ports and services...

What does running `wget` in the CLI from s1 to s2 says?

Comment: how to run wget in the CLI from s1 to s2? I am using windows 7 machine.

Comment: lol. Please paste the exact code you are using. We need to see the server addresses and ports. Also, what OS does the servers run?