# PHP Picking information from another web page

Tags: php, html

Is there any way where we can pick up some information from another web page and display it on our browser (after making some modifications) using PHP? Suppose the page from where I want to pick information from has the URL http://sk.com. (Basically, i want to pick up information from a table on a web page and sort it according to a particular column and then display the details.)

---

### What if we want to pick information from the local server, and not an external URL?

---

****Any other good source to learn more about php curl? also can it be done with domdoc?

Comment: use CURl, USE API if available, get content in file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php curl for this things You can refer about php curl here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

[PHP CURL from a specific server to another specific server not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991668/php-curl-from-a-specific-server-to-another-specific-server-not-working)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: "but other server should allow php curl request" --- this sounds wrong

Comment: Any other good source to know more about php curl?? also can it be done with domdoc?